# 403 you do not have permission

Tags: apache, localhost

Im setting up a localhost for the first time. I have something weird going on.

I running Fedora 24 with apache with the root folder at /var/www/html.
I have tested that this works by using vi to create an index.html which loads fine.

But now I have written some html and php files and moved them to the root dir. 
Imediately I get 403 message. Log writes Out this:

> [Tue Apr 04 16:06:52.116376 2017] [core:error] [pid 15260] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:40686] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/index.html

Now I create a test.html with sudo vi test.html and this file is able to load without a 403.

I then matched all the ownership and permissions to the file that loaded correctly.

And still nothing.

in the config file This stands out:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
     Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and:

```
   <Directory "/var/www/html">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

Am i missing somthing here?

Comment: This certainly should be a comment, so have a `#` in front of it: `Allow open access:`

Comment: Please add a list of file permissions in `/var/www/html` (and the folder itself, so `.`).

Comment: Did you check the permissions in your filesystem? change it so everyone can at least read that folder... 755 or something...whatever you need, as long as it is readable